# Halting Problem Oracle

Tags: logic, computation, computability-theory

Halting problem is unsolvable. There is no method to solve it, so no human can solve it.

So why is any theory utilising an oracle (which can solve halting problem) not simply nonsense?

Comment: No human can count up to infinity, yet I'd wager that the concept of infinity is not nonsense for you.

Comment: @Johan That's a human limitation, not a logical one. Unsolvability of halting problem is an established logical impossibility.

Comment: But there is not logical impossibility in having a machine with an oracle that solves the halting problem (for machines without oracle). What was proved impossible was to have a machine without oracle that solves the halting problem.

Comment: @Johan I can abstractly count up to infinity using a dot, a line, and an arrow between 0 and infinity. I don't claim that it's not humanly possible to count up to infinity, but I presume you mean verbally and the such.

Comment: @DennisFrancisBlewett Sure, I meant it in a very pragmatic way. I have the feeling that it is think kind of over-pragmatism that may give someone the idea that such abstractions (infinite line, machine with oracle solving the halting problem, etc.) are nonsense.

Comment: @Ajax You need to be more precise and careful in the claims. Looking at the details will dissolve that question.

Answer (score 4):

The Halting Problem is the problem of constructing a Turing Machine (TM) that, given any other Turing Machine, M, as input, along with additional input D, will tell you whether if you feed D to M, M will halt or not. A TM with an oracle (TMO) is not a TM; it is a fictional super-computational formalism more powerful than a TM.

You could prove that there is no TMO that can solve the halting problem for TMOs, but that doesn't mean that a TMO cannot solve the halting problem for TMs.

It is not inconsistent to postulate the existence of a machine more powerful than a TM. There are non-physically realizable models for such machines such as the [ITTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_machine) which proves that they are logically possible. It is an open question whether they are physically possible (although practically everyone believes they are not).

Comment: Another related concept is 'hypercomputer' which is a device capable of computing things that no Turing machine can. A number of theoretical hypercomputers have been described, but none can be built in our universe, or at least as far as we know. They make for interesting thought experiments.

Comment: Exactly, Oracle is fictional. Hence everything built on it is fictional.

Comment: Sure but fictionnal does not imply nonsense. The existence of complex numbers is somewhat fictional as well but still people can prove thing using those numbers and understand each other.

Comment: @ajax, the oracle is fictional in the same sense as pi, e, the square root of 2, 10^100^100, infinite sets, and anything else in mathematics that can't be realized physically. It is a coherent abstraction that can't be realized in the physical world, but can still be used to answer questions.

Comment: Oracle can't be realised logically, it is not just a question of physical realisability. I have no problem with Universal Turing Machines -they can't be realised physically (infinite tape requirement), but conceptually it is not a problem. I do understand that business of mathematics is to derive theorems, and not worry about objects under discourse. But what is the point of such an exercise if object is logically impossible?

Comment: @Ajax, the oracle is not logically impossible, as I explained in my answer. In fact, there are logical machines (not physically realizable) that can be used to solve the Halting Problem.